# What's with the lightsaber microphone in the Star Wars Holiday Special?

Tags: star-wars-holiday-special

I realize that asking a Watsonian question about the *Star Wars Holiday Special* is probably an exercise in futility.  However, this has been bugging me for years, so I'm asking this now, knowing there is little chance that there is going to be a definitive answer.

Along with performances by Art Carney, Bea Arthur, Harvey Korman (playing four separate characters), and the like, the *Special* features a musical number by [Jefferson Starship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefferson_Starship) (presumably chosen simply because the band had "Starship" in its name, and without Grace Slick who had just been fired from the band).

What I find eternally puzzling about this music video that Marty Balin's microphone appears at several points to be illuminated like a lightsaber.  Why?  Is it just supposed to be another psychedelic effect *in universe*?  Is there *any* allusion to such a lightsaber mic anywhere else in the *Star Wars* universe?

Comment: I really don't know what you are talking about. The Holiday special doesn't exist in my universe.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, honestly. ***All*** of the band's instruments show the same pink glow

Comment: @Loki It's ok. Wookie Life Day isn't for everyone. In fact, it's probably not for most people...